# Anomaly detection tsoutliers

Tags: r, anomaly-detection

I am interested in detecting outliers in a time series data, so  I decided to use the tsoutliers library implemented in R.
The results that I got from this library  were quite disappointing , in fact it seems that something went wrong with the algorithm because the outliers are concentrated in only one interval.
It seems that the algorithm is unable to find other outliers.
The time series that I am dealing with relates to an industrial process.
The data were collected over a 3 month period and the number of daily observations(and therefore the number of weekly observations) can vary, so the seasonal period is not well defined.
Moreover after removing the seasonality from the data with dummy variables the result does not change.
Here I leave the image with the outliers found.
On 23-05 the process did not work so there are no data for that day.
In the image, the algorithm was applied to the data without removing the seasonality.
Can you please explain to me what  the possible cause of this problem is and how I can solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to find outlier points, or outlier shapes?

If the latter, time series discords (the Matrix Profile) it fast and simple.
In fact the data in fig 18 of [a] looks similar to your data.

[a] https://www.cs.ucr.edu/%7Eeamonn/DAMP_long_version.pdf

Comment: I want to find outlier points. In particular I want to to find contextual outliers, global outliers and subsequent outliers(a subsequence that deviates from the rest of the data).